# Parsing from a list in python

Tags: python, list, api, indexing, discogs-api

I just finished some online tutorial and i was experimenting with [Discogs Api](https://github.com/discogs/discogs_client)

My code is as follows :

```
import discogs_client as discogs

discogs.user_agent = '--' #i removed it 

artist_input = raw_input("Enter artist\'s name : ")
artist = discogs.Artist(artist_input)

if artist._response.status_code in (400, 401, 402, 403, 404):
    print "Sorry, this artist %s does not exist in Discogs database" % (artist_input)
elif artist._response.status_code in (500, 501, 502, 503) :  
    print "Server is a bit sleepy, give it some time, won\'t you ._."
else:
        print "Artist : " + artist.name
        print "Description : " + str(artist.data["profile"])
        print "Members :",
        members = artist.data["members"]
        for index, name in enumerate(members):
            if index == (len(members) - 1):
                print name + "."
            else:    
                print name + ",",
```

The list's format i want to work with, is like this:

```
[<MasterRelease "264288">, <MasterRelease "10978">,  <Release "4665127">...
```

**I want to isolate those with MasterRelease, so i can get their ids**

I tried something like

```
for i in artist.releases:
        if i[1:7] in "Master":
            print i
```

or

```
for i in thereleases:
        if i[1:7] == "Master":
       print i
```

I;m certainly missing something, but it buffles me since i can do this

```
newlist = ["<abc> 43242"]
print newlist[0][1]
```

and in this scenario

```
thereleases = artist.releases    
print thereleases[0][1]
```

i get

```
TypeError: 'MasterRelease' object does not support indexing
```

Feel free to point anything about the code, since i have limited python knowledge yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the Python representation of objects, not strings. Each element in the list is an instance of the `MasterRelease` class.

These objects have an `id` attribute, simply refer to the attribute directly:

```
for masterrelease in thereleases:
    print masterrelease.id
```

Other attributes are `.versions` for other releases, `.title` for the release title, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. .title worked out, so i will try to read better the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are working with objects and assuming them to be strings. `artist.releases` is a list containing a number of objects.

```
newlist = ["<abc> 43242"]
print newlist[0][1]
```

This works because newlist is a list which contains a single element, a string. so `newlist[0]` gives you a string `'<abc> 43242'`. Applying `newlist[0][1]` gets you the second element of that string, that is `'a'`.

But this works only for objects that support *indexing*. And the objects that you are working with don't. What you are seeing in the list is a **string** representation of the object.

I cannot really help you further than this because I have no idea about the `MasterRelease` and the `Release` instances - but there should be some attribute in them that gets you the required value.

Answer (score 0):

If its only the `MasterRelease` that you want to filter then the code below might do:

`[master for master in artist.releases if 'MasterRelease' in str(type(master))]`

Assuming `MasterRelease` is not in the current scope. Or else you could:

`[master for master in artist.releases if isinstance(master, MasterRelease)]`